# Can I blow torch a table that is already stained?...what would happen? Thanks

Tags: staining

I have a table that is newly stained.  The idea of blow torching came after the fact.  Does anyone know what the results would be if you blow torch a stained table?

Answer (score 5):

As far as looks go the only way to know for sure what'll happen is to try it out, but on the safety side what's in the stain will be burned along with the wood and that may be a health hazard. So unless you're working out of doors or are wearing a good respirator (both wouldn't be a bad idea!) I would urge caution.

You can of course work around the problem, strip the stain, plane or sand off the surface, whatever is necessary so you're back to bare wood and then use the blowtorch.